# Do jQuery selectors return an array of HTML Element or jQuery Objects?

Tags: jquery

**What is stored in `Q`?**

```
Q = $('div');
Q2 = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

I can access each HTML element by using `Q[index]`, similar to `Q2[index]`; which makes it seem like `Q` is an array of HTML Elements.

On the other hand, I can do `Q.filter()`, but I **cannot** do `Q2.filter()`; which makes it seem like `Q` is an array of jQuery objects.

Or is it both, where `Q` is a jQuery object that holds a bunch of HTML elements?  If this was the case, wouldn't `console.log()` detect `Q` as an object with a collection of objects inside it? This fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/3s7tw/, shows that they are the same.

Note: I am aware that `Q.eq(index)` will return an object that can use jQuery methods.  I'm just wondering what exactly is `Q`

Answer (score 15):

The result is a `jQuery` object that behaves like both an array of `HTMLElements` which you get using `[]` and an `array` of `jQuery` objects which you get using `eq(index)`;

Comment: I would also note that iterator 'Q.each()' passes the HTMLElement object to the callback, as it iterates through Q as if it were an array. This was somewhat unexpected to me when I first used jQuery, although it makes perfect sense if you understand it's treating it as an array.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, `q` (the jQuery object) is an *array-like object*, which is effectively a wrapper around the set of selected DOM nodes. Consider this example:

HTML:

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

JS:

```
alert($("#example")) //Alerts something like "Object"
alert($("#example")[0]) //Alerts something like "HTMLDivElement"
alert(document.getElementById("example")); //Alerts something like "HTMLDivElement"
```

The second example above accesses the first raw DOM element in the collection (in this case, there is only one). You can achieve the same by using the jQuery `get(index)` method, but I used the normal array syntax to demonstrate that the jQuery object is similar to an array.

The jQuery wrapper object is what allows you to apply other jQuery methods to the matched set of elements. The DOM elements themselves do not have those methods, which is why in your example `Q2.filter()` does not work.

`Q2` is a raw DOM element. As a jQuery object is effectively a wrapper around a set of DOM elements, it's entirely possible to do this:

`alert($(document.getElementById("example"))); //Alerts something like "Object"`

In that example, `getElementById` returns the DOM element, which is then passed into the jQuery function, which returns the array-like jQuery object, allowing you to call other jQuery methods.

Answer (score 3):

Q is an object. It cheats and pretends to be an array be implementing all the usual array functions so firebug treats it that way. (Or maybe it starts as an array, but with stuff added.)

It contains a stack with all the previous selected elements (so you can use `.end()`) it has an actual array of the matched elements, and that's about it.

Try:

```
for(i in $('body')) console.log(i)
```

And you will see all the functions, etc.