# reset() function is not working, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a basic form that allows user to create dynamic input fields and when user submits the form the data is stored in the database. I am using AJAX for submitting the data because I do not want my page to reload. But after submitting the page, the data inserted my be removed from the fields and the form must be reset, but the reset funtion is not working.

Here is my code : check.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Dynamic Add Input Fields</header>
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" class="form-control name_list"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success" value="ADD"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function () {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input id="name" type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove" Value="X" /></td></tr>'); 
            });
            $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function () {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
            });
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"check.php",
                    data:$('#form1').serialize(),
                    success:function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#form1')[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Action file : check.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','Test2');

    if(!$conn) {
        echo 'Couldn\'t connect to database'.mysqli_error();
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $count = $length = '';
    $length = count($name);

    for($count=0 ; $count<$length ; $count++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `check1` (name) VALUES ('$name[$count]')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if(!$result) {
            echo 'Couldn\'t add data '.$count.mysqli_error();
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Everything else is working fine. Even the data is being stored in the database. The only problem is the reset function.
Thanks for help and your time.

Comment: change `$('#form1')[0].reset();` to `document.getElementById('form1').reset()` and it should work.

Comment: @Fuross He is already using jQuery, Why not use `$('form')`?

Comment: @Sid Joshi Because jQuery's `$()` returns just the HTML element and reset method needs to be called on the element object.

Comment: @Fuross Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993855/do-jquery-selectors-return-an-array-of-html-element-or-jquery-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `name="reset"`. If you do that, `$('#form1')[0].reset` refers to the button, not the function.

Change it to `name="resetButton"` or just get rid of the `name` attribute completely -- you don't need a name for an input that isn't submitted to the server.

Comment: Not working still. I removed the name but didn't get any luck. Thanks

Comment: Ok, after removing the ID and NAME both, its working...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"check.php",
    data:$('#form1').serialize(),
    success:function (data) {
       alert(data);
       $("#form1").trigger("reset");
    }
});
```