# Overloading [] operator for arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you overload the [] operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript)

Is it possible to overload the [] operator for arrays in Javascript?

For instance I would like to modify the behavior of the bracket so that when it accesses an index out of range it returns 0 instead of `undedined`.

I know I could probably get away with something like this:

```
function get(array, i) {
    return array[i] || 0;
}
```

But that's not really modifying the behavior of arrays the way I want.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the duplicate because SO's search system does not play nice with `[]` characters.

Answer (score 4):

Since `[]` is not an operator, you can't "override" it, but you can add property to `Array`'s prototype, which may be helpful in your specific case. Hovewer, it is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype):

```
Array.prototype.get = function(i, fallback) { return this[i] || fallback; }

a = [1, 2, 3]

a.get(0, 42)
1

a.get(4, 42)
42
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is not an operator, and you can't override it.

[You can override accessors for other javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (that is override `['somespecificvalue']` for writing or reading) but not the `[]` of arrays.

I'll add I'm glad you can't override it. I don't see the point except in making a whole application unreadable (an application where the basic syntactic elements can't be understood before you've read the whole code to be sure there isn't a change is unreadable).