# Can I overload JavaScript's indexing operator?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload JavaScript's indexing operator. I tried doing it like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.[] = function(i) {
}
```

…but the above code failed; I think the compiler doesn't support overloading the index operator. I really need such a method; is there any way to implement it?

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I had to venture I guess I think the OP wants to be able to do `obj[10]` and have it call his function with `i = 10`. [This blog post might help.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-Extending-JavaScript-Arrays-While-Keeping-Native-Bracket-Notation-Functionality.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overloading is not possible in javascript.

Check the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1711405/1903116

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that Javascript doesn't support overloading the indexing operator (I haven't looked into it, so I have no idea, but I bet there's a way).  It's that `[` is not a valid first character for a property name, so the entire name becomes invalid.

In case you're interested, the JIT compiler in Firefox 24 threw:

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

obj.[] = function(i) {
    ^
```

You can't reference invalid property names with the `.` syntax.  Regardless of how you want to use the syntax you've described above, you will ALWAYS come back to this issue. `[]` is not a valid property name, so it will always fail on an object.

As others have mentioned, you can use the bracket syntax to reference any invalid name, like `obj["[]"]`.

Here's a cut and paste from [Mathias Bynens' "Javascript Identifiers"](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
>   “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
>   or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any
>   U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner
>   characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark
>   (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or
>   “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.
>
> That’s it, really.