# Can I create a class [] operator in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

Is there a way to override the [] operation in typescript? We use 1.4 so we're fine with a solution that requires 1.4.

**Update:** I was horribly unclear in my initial question. What I meant was can I add that as an operator to a class. In my class I presently have a method:

```
public get(index : number) : LinkedListNode<t> {

    if (this._first === null || (index >= this._count)) {
        return null;
    }
    var node = this._first;
    while (index-- > 0) {
        node = node._next;
    }
    return node;
}
```

I would prefer to be able to call data[5] instead of data.get(5).

Is there a way to do this?

thanks & sorry for the incredibly inaccurate initial question.

Comment: Why would you want to out of interest?

Comment: As you [can't in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript), I doubt Typescript supports it.

Comment: @X.L.Ant your doubts are correct. It doesn't.

Comment: No, and don't do this.

Comment: I updated my question which significantly changed it - and therefore changed the answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: you can still write getter and setter for 0, 1, 2 etc, but the size will be hardcoded, e.g. for a vector class it's acceptable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

In response to your update to your question, no it's not possible to overload the index operator for a class—you can't do `data[5]` instead of `data.get(5)`.

In my opinion, the reason this has not been implemented is because JavaScript allows accessing an object's properties using brackets and that creates some ambiguity. For example, if `data.myProperty` is a property that exists and `data['myProperty']` is called, then it would be difficult to decide if it should return the `myProperty` property or if the string 'myProperty' should be passed to the index overload.

### Original Answer

It's not possible to change the result of:

```
var a = [];
```

Imagine the problems that could occur if people were allowed to change that behaviour? Library A could define it one way and then Library B could overwrite that with its own behaviour... meaning Library B now uses Library A's `[]` behaviour.

What you can do is add methods to `Array`'s prototype:

```
interface Array {
    log: () => void;
}

Array.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
};
```

Then use:

```
var a = [];
a.log();
```

*However, doing this is extremely not recommended!* You shouldn't be modifying objects you don't own because it can lead to unforeseen problems. The reason not to do this is similar to why changing `[]`'s behaviour would lead to problems:

1. Library A defines a `log` method.
2. Library B defines a `log` method that works differently.
3. Now the `log` method for Library A won't work as expected because it's using Library B's method.

**Recommendation**

I would suggest creating your own implementation of array:

```
class MyArray<T> implements Array<T> {
    private _underlyingArray : Array<T> = [];

    // implement methods for Array here

    log() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this._underlyingArray));
    }
}
```

Or create a helper class:

```
class ArrayHelper {
    static log<T>(a: Array<T>) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question which significantly changed it - and therefore changed the answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Yes, I saw. I updated my answer to answer it, but also kept the original in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Operators cannot be overloaded in JavaScript / TypeScript.

With ECMAScript 6, you'll be able to use [iterators](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html). TypeScript 1.5 adds [the support of Symbols](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#15) with the target ES6. But iterators are not available in TypeScript with ES5/3 as target.

Answer (score -5):

usually, arrays are a list of variables/values(maybe character/integer/float)

instead of this, you can manually use objects..
Example:

`var objtest = {first: "one", second:"two"};`
then you can use each element this way:

`objtest.first; -- outputs one
 objtest.second; -- outputs two`

if you want you can use it as each variable..

Example:

`var first = "one";
var second = "two" ;`

I prefer using the first way.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't talk about overloading `[]`.

Comment: Well you talked about OVERRIDE and not OVERLOAD which means I didn't do anything wrong, please do up vote my post.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address doing something different when `[]` is called.

Comment: _"Override an operation"_. Yes, literally, you're right! I upvote. ;)