# In Typescript, is there any way to write a class as a Array, so I can do class[i], like a List<T> in C#

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm a new game developer who started from C#.

Now I need to transfer one of my games to typescript.

I tried to customize a list in typescript which i'm very familiar to in C#.
my code is like below:

```
export class List {

private items: Array;
constructor() {
    this.items = [];
}

get count(): number {
    return this.items.length;
}

add(value: T): void {
    this.items.push(value);
}

get(index: number): T {
    return this.items[index];
}
contains(item: T): boolean{
    if(this.items.indexOf(item) != -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
clear(){
    this.items = [];
}
}
```

Still, I want to make like a array so I can do things like:

```
someList[i] = this.items[i];
```

I guess it's something like operator overload but I'm not quite sure.
 
Can any one tell me how to make it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply extend Array

```
export class List<T> extends Array<T> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    get count(): number {
        return this.length;
    }

    add(value: T): void {
        this.push(value);
    }

    get(index: number): T {
        return this[index];
    }

    contains(item: T): boolean {
        if (this.indexOf(item) != -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    clear() {
        this.splice(0, this.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, it works, except for the clear() method, it cant't be like this = [];

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the `private items: Array<T>` field anymore as that's handled by `Array<T>`

Comment: but when i run the code to test like this:    `let testList = new List<number>();`    `testList.add(1);`    it log error :    `TypeError: testList.add is not a function`

Comment: I have test and compiled to ES6 like this `tsc -target ES6`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect of overloading the indexing operator, you would have to [use a proxy to get the runtime behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658975) and then use an index signature for the typing, like this:

```
interface List<T> {
    [n: number]: T;
}
```

But proxies are serious machinery.  You might be better off living with the boilerplate of method calls.

Comment: Thanks! think you are right, better get used to work with arrays

Comment: This way we can impliment IList interface ,wel done Matt