# Modify array element access to make it 1-based index

Tags: javascript

I've run across a codewars exercise which I'm struggling with: https://www.codewars.com/kata/scraping-codewars-top-500-users/train/javascript

I want to be able to access an array as if was 1-indexed, instead of 0-indexed.

For example, if I have this array:

`let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I would like to do `a[5]` and get `5` as a result (instead of `4`).

So far, I've come up with this:

```
Array.prototype.get = function(i, fallback) {
  return this[i-1] || fallback;
}
```

And with:

```
class BaseOneArray extends Array {
    constructor(...args) { 
        super(...args); 
    }
    get(i, fallback) {
        return this[i-1];
    }
}
```

However, both of these approaches only work when accessing the array like this: `a.get(4)` but not when doing it like this: `a[4]`

How could I make the `[]` operators from an array work as if the array had a 1-based index?

The array must have the same number of items, so I can't just add a fill value in the first position to move all the elements one place up.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To influence property accesses you could use a proxy that increases every property access:

```
  array =  new Proxy(array, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      if(!isNaN(+prop)) --prop;
      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    },
    set(target, prop, value) {
      if(!isNaN(+prop)) --prop;
      return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
    },
  });
```

By proxying the underlying array still stays zero based, just your "view" of it is changed so if the array is used somewhere else that doesnt get affected.

Comment: maybe you should check for integer values as well ... and for 32 bit ... and positive ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the array then you can do something like this.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = [undefined, ...a];

console.log("a[5] is ", a[5]);
console.log("a[0] is ", a[0]); // Same as accessing any undefined index. See below
console.log("a[100] is ", a[100]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code test does not specify you need an array, it just says "*Leaderboard#position[i] should return the ith ranked User(1 based index)*". You should be able to simply use an object with numeric keys then:

```js
const leaderboard = yourFetchedAndParsedLeaderboardDomElementArray
  .reduce((acc, row, index) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [index + 1]: {
      // get the following ones from `row` somehow:
      name: ...,
      clan: ...,
      author: ...
    }
  }), {});
```

You can use the object spreading syntax if available rather than `Object.assign`.