# Vue: Watch array data variable doesnt work

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to watch an array declarated in data method (the 'validated' variable). I already have a watcher to an input (legal_name) and it works correctly but the array watcher doesnt give any response. Any idea?

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            legal_name : '',
            validated: [],
            errors: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
        validated() {
            console.log('modified')
        },
        legal_name(value) {
            this.eventName();
            this.legal_name = value;
            this.checkLength(value, 3);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkLength(value, lengthRequired) {
            if(value.length < lengthRequired) {
                this.errors[name] = `Debes ingresar al menos ${lengthRequired} caracteres`;
                this.validated[name] = false;
                return false;
            }

            this.errors[name] = '';
            this.validated[name] = true;
            return true;
        },
        eventName() {
            name = event.target.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Vue.set()` for arrays, and *NOT* use indexing such as

```
foo[3]= 'bar'
```

Vue *DOES* recognize some operations, such as `splice` and `push`, however.

Read more about it here:  https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/ and here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

So for your code, and using the `Vue` handy helper method `$set`:

```
this.validated.$set(name, true);
```

## Why...

Javascript does not offer a hook (overload) for the array index operator (`[]`), so `Vue` has no way of intercepting it.  This is a limitation of `Javascript`, not `Vue`.  Here's more on that:  [How would you overload the [] operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you!, i get it with `this.$set(this.validated, name, true)`. But the watch only works when the index is registred by first time `this.$set(this.validated, name, false)`, when i change it to true nothing happens.

Comment: 1. Try a deep watch.     2. Try replacing entire array after mutation. `this.validated=this.validated.slice()`

Comment: Also, you do not need this in your watcher: `this.legal_name = value;`

Comment: Also, where is `name` defined?