# How to create javascript objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set javascript objects dynamically?

I your create objects this way:

```
let data = {a: {b: 'value'}};
```

but I need to create it this way:

```
let data ['a'] ['b'] = 'value';
```

Object creation will happen within a loop dynamically. That's why I need the second way.

Comment: please! Help-me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in Javascript, because [] operator cannot override in JavaScript.

If you use ruby, you can by following way.

```rb
class MyHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    if has_key? key
      super
    else
      self[key] = self.class.new
    end
  end
end
my_hash = MyHash.new

my_hash[1][2][3] = "a"

puts my_hash
=> {1=>{2=>{3=>"a"}}}
```

This can be done by "[]" operator overriding.
JavaScript doesn't support "[]" operator overriding.

[How would you overload the [] operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript)

Then you should

```
lat data = {}
data[a] = data[a] ? data[a] : {}
data[a][b] = "value"
```

Comment: thank you my friend! I was able to solve my problem with your theoretical explanation. I was unaware that it is not possible to change the operator of a variable in javascript. Given this, I created the object type variable {} (which is already the right type) and managed to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
let data = {};
data['a'] = {'b': 'value'}
```