# Is it possible to implement indexer in a custom class in JavaScript or TypeScripe?

Tags: javascript, typescript

can I use sqare brackets on a custom class like in C#?
Or are the square brackets limmeted to Arrays in JavaScript?

The equavilent in C# would be like that:

```cs
    public class Contact
    {
        private string[] address = new string[3];
        public string this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return address[index];
            }
            set
            {
                address[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither JavaScript nor TypeScript has the *specific* feature you're looking for, but JavaScript does have [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects, which are extremely powerful and can be used for this. You'd need to implement the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) trap handlers (at minimum), and have the `Contact` constructor return a proxy rather than the instance itself. (If you return an object from the constructor, that overrides the default behavior of returning the newly-created instance.) The `get` handler gets called on every property "read" on the proxy, and the `set` handler gets called on every property "write" on the proxy:

```js
// ==== The implementation
const rexAllDigits = /^\d+$/;
const contactProxyHandlers = {
    get(target, key) {
        if (rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
            return target.address[key];
        }
        return target[key];
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
        if (rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
            return Reflect.set(target.address, key, value);
        }
        return Reflect.set(target, key, value);
    }
};
class Contact {
    constructor() {
        this.address = ["", "", ""];
        return new Proxy(this, contactProxyHandlers);
    }
}

// ==== Usage:
const c = new Contact();
c[0] = "address 0";
console.log(c[0], c.address[0]); // "address 0", "address 0"
c.example = "not an index property";
console.log(c.example);
```

In that example, I'm redirecting all property gets and sets that use all-digits property names to the `address` array on the `Contact` object, but passing through requests for other properties directly to the object.

Your C# version made `address` private. Soon you'll be able to use [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) to do that in JavaScript, too. Until then, if you want to make it private, you can use a `WeakMap` to do that, like this:

```js
// ==== The implementation -- private parts
// You'd keep these parts private, for instance in a module and not exported

const contactAddresses = new WeakMap();
const proxyTargets = new WeakMap();
const rexAllDigits = /^\d+$/;
const contactProxyHandlers = {
    get(target, key) {
        if (rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
            return contactAddresses.get(target)[key];
        }
        return target[key];
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
        if (rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
            return Reflect.set(contactAddresses.get(target), key, value);
        }
        return Reflect.set(target, key, value);
    }
};

// ==== The implementation -- public parts
// You'd make this available, for instance exporting it from the module

class Contact {
    constructor() {
        // Initialize the entry in the map. If/when this object is ready
        // for garbage collection, the entry will get removed automatically.
        contactAddresses.set(this, ["", "", ""]);
        const p = new Proxy(this, contactProxyHandlers);
        proxyTargets.set(p, this);
        return p;
    }
    showAddresses() {
        const t = proxyTargets.get(this);
        if (!t) {
            throw new Error("Invalid `this` value for Contact");
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(contactAddresses.get(t)));
    }
}

// ==== Usage:
const c = new Contact();
c[0] = "address 0";
console.log(c[0]); // "address 0"
c.showAddresses(); // "address 0", "", ""
c.example = "not an index property";
console.log(c.example);
```

The version using private fields would also need the `proxyTargets` `WeakMap`. It would look like this:

```
// ==== The implementation
class Contact {
    static #rexAllDigits = /^\d+$/;
    static #contactProxyHandlers = {
        get(target, key) {
            if (Contact.#rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
                return target.#address[key];
            }
            return target[key];
        },
        set(target, key, value) {
            if (Contact.#rexAllDigits.test(key)) {
                return Reflect.set(target.#address, key, value);
            }
            return Reflect.set(target, key, value);
        }
    };
    static #proxyTargets = new WeakMap();
    #address = ["", "", ""];
    constructor() {
        const p = new Proxy(this, Contact.#contactProxyHandlers);
        Contact.#proxyTargets.set(p, this);
        return p;
    }
    showAddresses() {
        const t = Contact.#proxyTargets.get(this);
        if (!t) {
            throw new Error("Invalid `this` value for Contact");
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(t.#address));
    }
}

// ==== Usage:
const c = new Contact();
c[0] = "address 0";
console.log(c[0]); // "address 0"
c.showAddresses(); // "address 0", "", ""
c.example = "not an index property";
console.log(c.example);
```

Comment: I've never even thought about returning the proxy inside the constructor, but it makes perfectly sense for proxies. Learnt something new today.