# Making a class iteratable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, oop, set

I have the following class:

```
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.group = [];
  }

  add(input) {
    if (!this.group.includes(input)) {
      this.group.push(input);
    }
  }

  static from(arr) {
    const group = new Group();
    for (let el of arr) {
      group.add(el);
    }
    this.group = group;
    return group;
  }

  has(elem) {
    return this.group.includes(elem);
  }
  delete(elem) {
    let newarr = this.group.filter((n) => n !== elem);
    this.group = newarr;
  }
}
```

what I want to do is this:

```
for (let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
// → a
// → b
// → c
```

that is to make the class an iterable object but I dont know how to do it.

note:

don’t just return the iterator created by calling the Symbol.iterator method on the array

Comment: why close the question when I dont have to use the symbol.iterator while answers use symbol.iterator

Comment: Because that's not what the answers in the other question say.

Comment: That's not what your restriction says. It says you shouldn't return the array's iterator.

Comment: restriction is symbol.iterator

Comment: That's not what it says. It says "Symbol.iterator method on the array". You do have to use `Symbol.iterator` to make your class iterable, that's the definition of iterable in JavaScript.

Comment: that's correct...

Comment: but first answer in the old question does that

Comment: Then use a different answer, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715252/1491895

Comment: better to reopen the question because he does not have restrictions which can give new answers

Comment: Duplicates don't have to be exactly the same. The answers are there, they're just not the accepted answer.

Comment: I gave you a link to the answer. If I were to reopen the question, I'd simply copy and paste that answer. And if I can do that, then there's no point in having a second question.

Comment: your restriction is also arbitrary. Why shouldn't you return the array's iterator if you can? If it's just for the homework assignment, how does this question help anyone in the future?

Comment: @Barmar It is probably worthwhile to define a new class GroupIterator. Iterator instances should have a property that tracks the current position in the group. Every time next is called, it checks whether it is done and, if not, moves past the current value and returns it.

The Group class itself gets a method named by Symbol.iterator that, when called, returns a new instance of the iterator class for that group.

Comment: You can't do that if `Group.from()` is required to return a `Group` and you want to iterate over that.

Comment: @Barmar not always from is required

Comment: What's the point of this `Group` class anyway? It appears to behave just like a standard `Set`.

Comment: @Bergi to see how Set works

Comment: If you use a different class, then the `Group` class has to expose a way to index specific elements, so that `GroupIterator` can reference them.

Comment: It basically amounts to the same thing, since you just need to know how to make `GroupIterator` iterable. And that's by giving it a `[Symbol.iterator]` method.

Comment: @Barmar that's my question

Comment: Add an `at(index)` method to `Group`, and call that from `GroupIterator`.

Comment: But your question specifically says it should work with `of Group.from(...)`, not `of new GroupIterator(Group.from(...))`

Comment: @Barmar I am a beginner in javaScript I would prefer the full answer to understand better

Comment: OK, then you need to show what you tried. SO is not a "do my homework for me" site. We'll help you fix your code, we won't write it for you.

Comment: Add your attempt to the question and I'll reopen.

Comment: @Barmar alright give me  5 minutes

Comment: ```class GroupIterator {
     constructor(group) {
    this.group = group.group;
    this.index = 0;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.index < this.group.length) {
      return { value: this.group[this.index++], done: false };
    } else {
      return { done: true };
    }
  }
} ```

Comment: calling inside the group [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return new GroupIterator(this);
  }

Comment: @KingPalca Notice that implementation will cause you troubles when [adding or deleting elements during the iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943995/1048572)

Comment: Btw, "*make the class an iterable object but I dont know how to do it.*" seems to not (or no longer?) be your actual question. You might want to [edit] your question to ask about what you actually want to know.

Comment: Please edit that into the question. Code in comments has no formatting and is unreadable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613518/is-it-possible-to-implement-indexer-in-a-custom-class-in-javascript-or-typescrip for how you can use a Proxy to implement `[]` indexing in a custom class. Or you could use a named method, like my suggested `this.group.at(this.index++)`.